# Problems iterating through subfolders to add images in open pyxl

Tags: python, image, loops, iteration, openpyxl

So at my work we have several contracts for producing photologs. Essentially an excel workbook where each sheet has 4 images arranged top left, top right, bottom left, and bottom right. The thing that takes the longest is inserting and formatting the images into the workbook. I am not a rock solid programmer, and much of the python work I have done in the past is based around utilizing arc gis tools in python (arcpy). That being said I decided to tackle this somewhat daunting, at least for me, project.

Here is everything I have imported. I know at this point some of these modules are not being used.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import worksheet
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl import formatting
from openpyxl import worksheet
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
import glob
import os
from natsort import natsorted
```

For this to work right, I need it to create a worksheet with a specified format for each sub directory inside my main directory. I am proud as I have managed to get python to create a sheet with the correct format for each folder in my main subfolder.

```
wb = Workbook()

Path = r'C:\Users\wes\Desktop\PhotoLog\Photos'
count = 0
folder = os.listdir(Path)
for folders in folder:
    count += 1
    wb.create_sheet(str(count))
    ws = wb[str(count)]
    ws.page_setup.orientation = ws.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
    ws.page_setup.paperSize = ws.PAPERSIZE_A5
    ws.sheet_view.view = "pageLayout" 

    for row in range(1,45):
            for col in range(1,45):
                ws.row_dimensions[row].height = 18
                col_letter = get_column_letter(col)
                ws.column_dimensions[col_letter].width = 3
                ws.merge_cells('A12:C13')
                ws.merge_cells('D12:V13')
                ws.merge_cells('W12:Y13')
                ws.merge_cells('Z12:AR13')
                ws.merge_cells('A25:C26')
                ws.merge_cells('D25:V26')
                ws.merge_cells('W25:Y26')
                ws.merge_cells('Z25:AR26')
                
                     
wb.remove(wb['Sheet'])
```

Note that for whatever reason I have to remove the default sheet created by open pyxl.

Where I am running into a snag is inputting the photos.
The photos are saved inside a folder inside a folder. There are anywhere from 1-4 photos in each of these final subfolders. The path looks something like Main/subfolders/photo.jpg (see included image). In the full run there will be upwards of 20 subfolders, making a workbook with over 20 sheets. I have been able to get it to work where one sub folder correctly inputs, but I have not been able to make all subfolders loop and input in their respective sheets correctly.

This is the code that works for one folder:

```
# images list
images = []
for filename in natsorted(glob.glob('Photos/1/*.jpg')):
        images.append(filename)

# insert images
for index, image in enumerate(images):
    if index == 0:
        ws.add_image(Image(image), anchor='E2')
    elif index == 1:
        ws.add_image(Image(image), anchor='AA2')
    elif index == 2:
        ws.add_image(Image(image), anchor='E15')
    else:
        ws.add_image(Image(image), anchor='AA15')
```

Here is the code I am trying to use to loop through the sub folders:

```
# images list
count2 = 0
count2 += 1
for files in Path + '\\' + str(count2):
    images = []
    for filename in natsorted(glob.glob(r'C:\Users\wes\Desktop\PhotoLog\Photos\\' + str(count2) + '/*.jpg')):
            images.append(filename)

    # insert images
    for index, image in enumerate(images):
        if index == 0:
            ws.add_image(Image(image), anchor='E2')
        elif index == 1:
            ws.add_image(Image(image), anchor='AA2')
        elif index == 2:
            ws.add_image(Image(image), anchor='E15')
        else:
            ws.add_image(Image(image), anchor='AA15')
```

I know this is quite a long winded question, but any help would be greatly appreciated!!

-WS

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of the last code snippet should be changed to something like:

```
# images list
count2 = 0
while True:
    count2 += 1
    images = []
    for filename in natsorted(glob.glob(r'C:\Users\wes\Desktop\PhotoLog\Photos\\' + str(count2) + '/*.jpg')):
            images.append(filename)
    
    if len(images) == 0:
        break
        
    # insert images
```

and then continue unchanged.

The original for-loop `for files in Path + '\\' ...` iterates over a string, which means to iterate over the characters of the string.

This code assumes that the numbering of the subfolders is consecutive (if there isn't a subfolder `3`, no subfolders with higher numbers exist).

The inner for-loop can also be omitted, resulting in:

```
# images list
count2 = 0
while True:
    count2 += 1
    images = natsorted(glob.glob(r'C:\Users\wes\Desktop\PhotoLog\Photos\\' + str(count2) + '/*.jpg')):
    
    if len(images) == 0:
        break
        
    # insert images
```

Comment: So I attempted both of these options and I couldn't get either of them just right. The code looks like has looped through the insertion portion, however it is just inserting the different images on top of one another. It is also only inserting into the last available sheet. What I want is for the images in forlder "1" to insert into sheet "1" and so forth.